# An apparent inconsistency in the form of Spin-z operator for spin 1/2 system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, eigenvalue

**Problem:**

This is problem 7 from the first chapter of *Modern Quantum Mechanics* by Sakurai (page 59).

> Consider a ket space spanned by the eigenkets $\{ \mid a'\rangle \}$ of some Hermitian operator $A$. There is no degeneracy.
>
> (a) Prove that $\prod\limits_{a'} (A - a')$ is the null operator.
>
> (b) Explain the significance of $\prod\limits_{a'' \neq a'} \frac {(A - a'')}{(a' - a'')}$.
>
> (c) Illustrate (a) and (b) using $A$ set equal to $S_z$ of a spin $\frac{1}{2}$ system.

---

**My Work**

1. Construction of null operator and identity operator from eigenbasis of Hermitian operator:

(a) To show that it's a null operator it's sufficient to take some arbitrary $\mid \gamma \rangle$ belonging to the linear span of the eigenbasis $\{ \mid a' \rangle\}$, and show that

$$\left(\prod\limits_{a'}(A - a')\right) \mid \gamma \rangle = \left| 0 \right\rangle$$ (equation 1)

So, we have

$$A \mid a' \rangle = a' \mid a' \rangle$$ (equation 2)

and

$$\mid \gamma \rangle = \sum_{a'} \langle a'\mid \gamma \rangle \mid a'\rangle$$ (equation 3)

Using (3) in the LHS of (1), therefore, yields,

$$\sum_a' \langle a' \mid \gamma \rangle \prod\limits_{a''}(A-a'') \mid a' \rangle  = \sum_{a'} \langle a' \mid \gamma \rangle \prod\limits_{a''}(a' - a'') \mid a' \rangle = \left| 0 \right\rangle $$ (equation 4)

as when $a'' = a'$ inside the continued product, we get a $0$.

(b) From the previous calculation it's clear that:

$$\prod\limits_{a'' \neq a'} \frac {A - a''}{a' - a''} \mid \gamma \rangle = \sum_{a'} \langle a' \mid \gamma \rangle \cdot 1 \cdot\mid a' \rangle = \mathbb{I} \mid \gamma \rangle$$

$$\Longrightarrow \prod\limits_{a'' \neq a'} \frac {A - a''}{a' -a''} = \mathbb{I}$$ (equation 5)

(c) Illustration for $A = S_z$ of a spin $\frac {1}{2}$ system:

Let $\mid + \frac {1}{2} \rangle$, $\mid - \frac {1}{2} \rangle$ be the eigenvectors of $S_z$ operator. The $S_z$ operator can be decomposed as:

$$S_z = \mathbb{I}\cdot S_z\cdot \mathbb{I} = \left(\mid + \frac {1}{2} \rangle \langle + \frac {1}{2} \mid + \mid - \frac {1}{2} \rangle \langle - \frac {1}{2} \mid \right) S_z \left( \mid + \frac {1}{2} \rangle \langle + \frac {1}{2} \mid + \mid - \frac {1}{2}\rangle \langle - \frac {1}{2} \mid \right)$$
$$= \langle + \frac {1}{2} \mid S_z \mid + \frac {1}{2} \rangle \cdot\mid + \frac {1}{2}\rangle \langle + \frac {1}{2} \mid + \langle - \frac {1}{2} \mid S_z \mid  -\frac {1}{2} \rangle \cdot\mid  -\frac {1}{2} \rangle \langle - \frac {1}{2} \mid$$
$$= \frac {\hbar}{2} \left( \mid + \frac {1}{2} \rangle \langle + \frac {1}{2} \mid - \mid - \frac {1}{2} \rangle \langle - \frac {1}{2} \mid \right)$$ (equation 6)

The null operator $\hat{O}= (S_z - \frac {\hbar}{2}).(S_z + \frac {\hbar}{2}) = S_z^2 - \frac {\hbar ^2}{4} \mathbb{I}$ and the identity operators are $\mathbb{I} = \frac {S_z}{\hbar} + \frac {\mathbb{I}}{2}$, $- \frac {S_z}{\hbar} + \frac {\mathbb{I}}{2}$

**Where I'm having trouble**

The problem is with the very last result, on the last line of the page. I am getting

$$S_z=\frac{\hbar}{2}\mathbb{I}$$ and also $$S_z=-\frac{\hbar}{2}\mathbb{I}$$

which is clearly not correct. My guiding equation has been equation 5 (which seems to be correct). I have put $A=S_z$ of a spin 1/2 system in equation 5. I cannot locate the flaw in the steps.

> So, where's the mistake? Please share your views.

**Note**: I should be sort of double lined and hollow like in the last sentence of "my work", but the command I found didn't work. Also, the arrow should be the same style. The command I found for that didn't work either. I replaced them with a normal I and a normal arrow. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sABou.jpg) is the link to the work page image, if anyone wants it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43375/discussion-between-subhobrata-chatterjee-and-heather).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43379/discussion-on-question-by-subhobrata-chatterjee-an-apparent-inconsistency-in-the).

Comment: Thanks everyone for taking the pains to bear with the image until heather and later Mithrandir24601 fixed it.

Comment: @DavidZ I'm not sure I understand why this is off-topic - the tagline doesn't quite apply since it definitely asks about a specific concept albeit slightly mathematical relating to hermitian operators. It's from sakurai which is a standard enough text so in principle future user could find it helpful, and it certainly has a lot of effort shown.

Comment: @snulty What it asks is "So, where's the mistake?" That's very clearly not about a specific concept - it's exactly the sort of question the homework-like close policy is meant for.

Comment: @DavidZ I think that's a bit of a harsh and narrow view, it's punishing a user for doing more work than less work. One could've easily said 'I don't know what the operator in part b) is' and done nowhere near as much work as op. If op didn't have a mistake he/she wouldn't have asked the question! Rather than taking up a long comment conversation I'll move to meta a little later today.

Comment: @snulty Indeed, if the OP's problem is that they don't know what the operator in part (b) is, they could have asked that and it would be a better question. Doing (or at least _showing_) more work is not always a good thing. We can certainly continue this on meta or in [chat].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some notes on the other parts as well as the spin $z$ one:

- I would write the $0$ in the vector space as $0$ and not $\left|0\right\rangle$, since the latter suggests it's an eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$, but you wouldn't consider $0$ as a proper eigenvector since it would have everything in the field as it's eigenvalue.
- For part $b)$ note if $\left|\gamma\right\rangle=\sum\limits_a \langle a|\gamma\rangle\left|a\right\rangle$, then acting with $\prod\limits_{a''\neq a'}\frac{A-a''}{a'-a''}$ gives 
  $$\sum\limits_a \langle a|\gamma\rangle\prod\limits_{a''\neq a'}\frac{a-a''}{a'-a''}\left|a\right\rangle=\sum\limits_a\delta_{a,a'}\langle a|\gamma\rangle\left|a\right\rangle=\langle a'|\gamma\rangle\left|a'\right\rangle$$
  Since if $a\neq a'$ then $a''$ can equal $a$. Or if $a=a'$, then the above is a product of $1$'s. Significance: Does it look like a projection operator?
- We write $\left|\gamma\right\rangle=\langle \uparrow\big|\gamma\rangle\left|\uparrow\right\rangle+\langle \downarrow\big|\gamma\rangle\left|\downarrow\right\rangle$. Then 
  $$\left(S_z-\frac{\hbar}{2}\right)\left(S_z+\frac{\hbar}{2}\right)\left|\gamma\right\rangle = 0\cdot\left(S_z+\frac{\hbar}{2}\right)\langle \uparrow\big|\gamma\rangle\left|\uparrow\right\rangle+\left(S_z-\frac{\hbar}{2}\right)\cdot 0\cdot \langle \downarrow\big|\gamma\rangle\left|\downarrow\right\rangle=0$$
  Similarly (now there's only one term in the product) I'll pick $a'=\hbar/2$ value:
  $$\frac{\left(S_z+\frac{\hbar}{2}\right)}{\hbar/2+\hbar/2}\left|\gamma\right\rangle=\langle \uparrow\big|\gamma\rangle\cdot \frac{\hbar/2+\hbar/2}{\hbar/2+\hbar/2}\cdot\left|\uparrow\right\rangle+\langle \downarrow\big|\gamma\rangle\cdot 0\cdot\left|\downarrow\right\rangle=\langle \uparrow\big|\gamma\rangle\left|\uparrow\right\rangle$$
  as expected

Comment: Thanks a lot. My mistake was in that I messed up the index for the expansion of the $|\gamma>$ state vector in b. It must be different from a' and a''.

Comment: @SubhobrataChatterjee no problem, happy to help!